# Regex to match all excess and trailing NewLines

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to find a C#-compatible regex to **match all excess newlines** – including empty/whitespace-only lines – allowing to replace:

```
first line
    second line

third line
```

like:

```
first line
    second line
third line
```

*without* any trailing newlines.

The well-known multi-line `^\s*$` does *not* match the last newline.

I was able to come up with **`(?<!\S+)\r\n|(\r\n)+\z`** which:

1. works, both in single-line and multi-line modes
2. is ugly and probably slow

Was anyone able to come up with a *simple* regex to do the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for that is, that `$` matches before a `\n` at the end of the string if there is nothing in the last row.

For the empty rows in between

```
^\s*^
```

`^` matches after a newline `\n`. So this matches whitespace from a start of a row to the next.

For the last empty row, you need to match from before the last newline all whitespace till the end of the string

```
$\s*\z
```

and in combination

```
^\s*^|$\s*\z
```

`\z` The match must occur at the end of the string

See [Anchors on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions)

My test:

```
string s = "This is the first row\n\nThis is the third\n    \nThis the fifth\n";

string result = Regex.Replace(s, @"^\s*^|$\s*\z", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Console.WriteLine(result);

Console.WriteLine("fin");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I tried a lot of these variants, and all - including yours - seems to work, but just ignore the last newline in the text.

Comment: @ViktorSvub, I did some tests and changed my answer.

Comment: According to my testing, this is almost OK :) It only needs to be modified to not leave a hanging '\r' at the end: 
`^\s*^|\r$\s*\z`

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the trailing newline, how about a hybrid approach:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"^\s+$", "", RegexOptions.Multiline).TrimEnd()
```

Simple and readable.

Comment: I know about this possibility, but I wanted to know if there is a way to do it purely in a C#-compatible regex.

Comment: Sorry, I personally don't like to use alternation, but this works: `@"^\s+$|\s+\z"` (replace pattern above). And +1 for @stema - nice explanation and link to anchors.